# raise custom exception in python

Tags: python, exception, raise

I could not get what is wrong with the code ? when I execute nothing happens. I am expecting my custom error message.

```
def testing():
  try:
    raise Exception('My error!')
  except:
    pass

testing()
```

Comment: What did you think `except: pass` means?

Comment: I wanted to raise a custom exception. so I did it in try block and left except block to do nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are successfully raising an error. And the try/catch statements sees it, and goes to `catch` as you have raised an error.

To fully customize errors you can declare them as so:

```
class CustomError(Exception):
    pass
raise CustomError("An error occurred")
```

results in

```
__main__.CustomError: An error occurred
```

Comment: You can also define an `__init__` function so that there's no need to pass an error string, the class can provide it.

Answer (score 5):

You are raising an exception successfully. But you are catching that with try/except block. So nothing happens unless you describe it in except block.